# Regex for a string/date

Tags: sql-server, regex, powershell

I am trying to  find a regex  to read a line that contains the date and time from a text file to add to a select statement like the one below (taken from [here](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/sqlpfeil/2012/12/04/working-with-sqlio-and-analyzing-its-output/)):

```bsh
$sourceFile = "C:\1\results_G.TXT"
$filedata = Get-Content $sourceFile | Out-String
$Results = $filedata.Split([string[]]"sqlio v1.5.SG", [StringSplitOptions]::RemoveEmptyEntries) |
           select @{Name="Threads"; Expression={[int]([regex]::Match($_, "(\d+)?\sthreads\s(reading|writing)").Groups[1].Value)}}
```

This is the format of the line I am trying to read:

```
Thu 08/12/2016  0:15:00.15
```

Comment: Your code is nearly unreadable without the processed text. Please provide a [mcve] BTW all the backticks aren't needed with a pipe or a comma as the last sign of a line.

Comment: have edited now, thanks for your feedback :)

Comment: Your edit does not include a [mcve] as requested. Follow the link to find out what a MCVE is, and then edit your post again to provide one.

Comment: have edited again , thanks

Comment: `[a-z]{3} \d{2}/\d{2}/\d{4} [ 12]\d:\d{2}:\d{2}\.\d{2}`

Comment: Thank you. How do I capture the values into a select statement similar to the above? this doesnt seem to work:

Comment: like this     `@{Name="Date"; Expression={[int] ([regex]::Match($_,"[a-z]{3} \d{2}/\d{2}/\d{4} [ 12]\d:\d{2}:\d{2}\.\d{2}").Groups[1].Value)}}`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following regex:

```
([a-zA-Z]{3})\s+?(\d{2})\/(\d{2})\/(\d{4})\s+?(\d{1,2}):(\d{2}):(\d{2})\.(\d{2})
```

*Here is a running example in JavaScript:*

```js
var string = "There was something on Thu 08/12/2016  0:15:00.15. On Fri 09/12/2017 11:20:30.20 was something else.";
var regex = /([a-zA-Z]{3})\s+?(\d{2})\/(\d{2})\/(\d{4})\s+?(\d{1,2}):(\d{2}):(\d{2})\.(\d{2})/g;

var match = regex.exec(string);

while(match !== null) {
  console.log({
    match: match[0],
    weekDay: match[1],
    day: match[2],
    month: match[3],
    year: match[4],
    hour: match[5],
    minute: match[6],
    second: match[7],
    centiseconds: match[8]
  });
  
  match = regex.exec(string);
}
```

Comment: Thank you , I am trying to get the regex aded as part of a select statement, and get the value into a property called date, like this - could you please tell me how can this be done                                        `@{Name="Date"; Expression={[int] ([regex]::Match($_,"[a-zA-Z]{3})\s+?(\d{2})\/(\d{2})\/(\d{4})\s+?(\d{1,2}):(\d{2}):(\d{2})\.(\d{2}").Groups[1].Value)}}`